# "needs more focus": Significantly different from former "too broad" close reason

Tags: bug, close-reasons

The new "needs more focus" wording is

> **Needs more focus**
>   This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

And that doesn't cover the 80%* of questions we used to close with this close reason for actually *being too broad*.

For example,

> How is the Fourier transform useful in signal processing?

**is** a single question, but we don't have a close reason for that anymore. It **is** parsecs to broad to be answered.

Can we fix this? It's a bug, since it effectively breaks the feedback loop between moderation and askers.

---

* like 82.34% of statistics, this number is made up

---

Also asking an equivalent question on EE.SE, since they are much bigger and might have a different view on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, I think, that the standard close reasons from SO changed.

These are the current ones:

[image: Standard reasons]

i.e. Duplicate, Needs more focus, and Needs details or clarity.

The other options are:

[image: Other options for closure]

and we only have three that we can change: General programming, working code, and homework question.

I'd be happy to change one of those three back to "Too Broad", but I'm not sure which one to remove.

Comment: uh, that's an interesting problem!

Comment: If we're willing to interpret "multiple questions" as including single questions that imply a potentially infinite number of other questions, it can technically count as "too broad." :)

Comment: @datageist LOL. :-) Yes, we could. :-)